# AWS codepipline has disabled polling. how can I restart polling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

Previous setting.

When uploading source code to code commit, `CodePipeline` is triggered automatically.

However,one day suddenly , I met this message on `CodePipeline`

```
As of 2 months ago, CodePipeline has disabled polling in this pipeline because it hasn't run in the 30 days prior. Use the recommended event-based mechanism to start new pipeline executions.
```

Now `CodePipeline` is not triggered automatically.

I searched around the `CodePipeline` and `CodeCommit` console, but could not find the specious setting.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The AWS CodePipeline has disabled the polling for inactive pipelines effective May 25, 2023. An inactive pipeline is defined as one that has not had a pipeline execution started in the last 30 days. They recommend to change the pipeline from polling to event based with the use of Amazon EventBridge, or AWS CodeStar Connections, or webhooks as the trigger mechanism for your source.

Answer (score 0):

Arpit is correct, this is part of AWS bases on their new policies.  For pipelines that don't run occasionally I would suggest an event bridge trigger that calls a lambda to execute your pipeline build based on a repository event.  We did something similar on our side.  Here is a link that may help you.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found it documented, but after using the "Release change" button to manually trigger a deployment, my CodePipeline started polling for changes again.

Answer (score 0):

You need edit the pipeline and save, you don't change anything and the pipeline enable again